# Can Pascal's Triangle be expressed as a exponential equation?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, exponential-function, exponentiation

Pascal's triangle seems to follow a pattern. `11row-1` outputs `PascalTriangle(row)` while `row ≤ 5`, but `116-1` outputs `161051`. However if you used Base<sub>100</sub>, you could go further.

So, my conjecture is that `11row-1` will be equal to the corresponding row in Pascal's Triangle, given that all calculations are done without a Base. For example, `116-1` would return `15101051`, not `161051`.

I asked my teacher about this, and we argued about it, him saying that it would have to break at some point, but I argued that it couldn't, it had no base, so there would never be carrying over, and thus no discrepancies.

Comment: Base 0?  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The pattern you've discovered is a known (perhaps not widely known) property of Pascal's triangle. Recall that each row gives the coefficients of the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ and that any number can be written as a sum of powers of 10. Substitute $x=10$ and the pattern should make sense for the first five rows.

Comment: @Brody, thanks for your answer. I can't seem to upvote it. Don't know why.

Comment: I don't think you have enough reputation yet for [that privilege](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Anyway, it's just a comment on your post, not an actual answer. A good answer might address how (if even possible) to have each row truly look like the digits of $11^n$ in some base, or something vaguely of that effect.